# ValueError: could not convert string to float: Model

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is what my .dat file looks like:

```
Model                   z                   x                   M                   L                   T          Lin Period         Growth rate                logT                logP                logM
   24                0.02                 0.7                 5.4                1500                5150              6.4025          0.00061948             8.54675             1.85669              1.6864
   26                0.02                 0.7                 5.4                1500                5250               5.954           0.0017293             8.56598             1.78406              1.6864
   29                0.02                 0.7                 5.4                1500                5400              5.3715           0.0022253             8.59415             1.68111              1.6864
   31                0.02                 0.7                 5.4                1500                5500              5.0308           0.0015741              8.6125             1.61558              1.6864
```

I am trying to plot the T column on an inverted x axis and the L column on the y axis. Here is a minimal version of my Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('PostiveGrowth_SetC_PeriodRange1.dat')

plt.plot(data[:,5],data[:,4])
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.ylabel('Luminosity (Lsun)')
plt.suptitle('Set A Instability Strip')

plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Model
```

I am running this in terminal in Ubuntu with python version 2.7.17.

**Edit:** I figured out the problem, it was the strings in the first row. Is there a way to skip the first row so I can just plot the floats?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: how about `data[1:, : ]` ? it gets all except first row. And you could use `data  = data[1:, : ]` or `plot( data[1:,5], data[1:,4] )`

Comment: From the docs, [loadtxt()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) has `skiprows` parameter. Perhaps try using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the first line

```
data = np.loadtxt('PostiveGrowth_SetC_PeriodRange1.dat',skiprows=1)
```